# Pandas group by two columns and count the second column value by each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of domains could someone tell me how I can filter domains with more than one extension with Pandas.

I grouped it by this code but I got this result:

```
dfActive.groupby(['domain','ext'])['ext'].nunique()
```

Result:

```
domain         com     1
sample         com     1
mashhadmap     com     1
               net     1
```

Expected Result:

```
mashhadmap     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use if need count per first level `domain` by aggregate `sum`:

```
dfActive.groupby(['domain','ext'])['ext'].nunique().groupby(level=0).sum()
```

If need filter values if duplicated per first level:

```
s = dfActive.groupby(['domain','ext'])['ext'].nunique()
s = s[s.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]

#and then if need aggregate sum
out = s.groupby(level=0).sum()
```